# Programmatically trigger event on element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, eventtrigger

I have (mostly `<select>`) elements that are being dynamically added to the document. To make sure that all elements (even those that will be added in the future) have `click` and `change` event handlers binded to them, I use the `$(document).on` method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cfield_fieldtype', function(){
     // do something... 
});

$(document).on('change', '.cfield_fieldtype', function(){
    // do some other stuff... 
});
```

At some point upon a function call, I want to reset my `<select>` elements, so set the first `<option>` of each as the `selected`. But when this happens I'd like to programatically trigger the `click` and `change` events as if it was done by user interaction.
If I set the first option as `selected`, that will not trigger the `click` event of course, but it won't trigger the `change` event as well. When I try to fire these events on the elements they won't react and do nothing. Here is the code:

```
$("#cfield_panel\\["+unique+"\\] select").each(function(){
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).val($("[name='"+name+"'] option:first").val());
    $(this).triggerHandler('click');
    $(this).triggerHandler('change');
});
```

So how could I trigger these event?

Comment: provide relevant HTML in question and minimalistic sample to replicate issue

Answer (score 0):

use `.click()` and `.change()`:

```
$(this).click();
$(this).change();
```

or `.trigger()` along with event:

```
$(this).trigger('click');
$(this).trigger('change');
```

Comment: *There is no method in jQuery called `.triggerHandler()`.* [Of course there is](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/).

Comment: @ACs: try putting alert before trigger statement to check whether the code is being executed or not.

Comment: @Milind Anantwar: Alerts both before and after the trigger statements are executed.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method instead which lets events propagate (because you are delegating events):

```
$(this).trigger('click');
$(this).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this is a good answer?